# continuous with special property is convex

Tags: calculus, general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x,y\in A:f(\frac{x+y}{2})\leq\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(y)).$

**Prove** that $f$ is convex.

I previously proved that for a general function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$:

$f$ is convex if and only if the set  $\Gamma^+(f)=\{(x,y):y>f(x)\}\subset A\times\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $A$ is convex, and let $x,y\in A$ be given.  Then we have
$$f\left(\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{3}{4}y\right)=f\left(\frac{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+y}{2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left[f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+f(y)\right]\leq\frac{1}{4}f(x)+\frac{3}{4}f(y).$$
And by repeated iteration, we have
$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y),$$
whenever $\lambda=\frac{m}{2^n}$ with $n\in\mathbb N$ and $0\leq m\leq 2^n$ (what is sometimes called a dyadic rational). Since $f$ is continuous, and rationals of this form are dense in $[0,1]$, the result is obtained.

Answer (score 4):

You would like to show $$f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y)\le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$$
for all x,y and $0<\lambda<1$.
Move to dyadic rationals first from the given info and then to any real in $(0,1)$ using density.